# Can this numeric range regex be refactored?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a number range:

**-9223372036854775808** to **9223372036854775807**

```
^(?:922337203685477580[0-7]|9223372036854775[0-7]\d{2}|922337203685477[0-4]\d{3}|92233720368547[0-6]\d{4}|9223372036854[0-6]\d{5}|922337203685[0-3]\d{6}|92233720368[0-4]\d{7}|9223372036[0-7]\d{8}|922337203[0-5]\d{9}|92233720[0-2]\d{10}|922337[0-1]\d{12}|92233[0-6]\d{13}|9223[0-2]\d{14}|922[0-2]\d{15}|92[0-1]\d{16}|9[01]\d{17}|[1-8]\d{18}|\d{0,18}|-(?:922337203685477580[0-8]|9223372036854775[0-7]\d{2}|922337203685477[0-4]\d{3}|92233720368547[0-6]\d{4}|9223372036854[0-6]\d{5}|922337203685[0-3]\d{6}|92233720368[0-4]\d{7}|9223372036[0-7]\d{8}|922337203[0-5]\d{9}|92233720[0-2]\d{10}|922337[0-1]\d{12}|92233[0-6]\d{13}|9223[0-2]\d{14}|922[0-2]\d{15}|92[0-1]\d{16}|9[01]\d{17}|[1-8]\d{18}|\d{0,18}))?$

// space for easier copy and paste
```

Yes, I know it sounds crazy, but there's a long story behind this. I can't figure out how to do this in JavaScript by just checking a range, because of the size of the number, and this must be accurate.

Here's the thought process in breaking this thing down. I just started with the max number and worked my way down, then worked on the negative by just adding the - in the regex. You'll obviously have to copy and paste this thing somewhere to see it all. Also, could be mistakes. Made my head nearly explode.

- 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
- 922337203685477580[0-7]
- 9223372036854775[0-7][0-9]{2}
- 922337203685477[0-4][0-9]{3}
- 92233720368547[0-6][0-9]{4}
- 9223372036854[0-6][0-9]{5}
- 922337203685[0-3][0-9]{6}
- 92233720368[0-4][0-9]{7}
- 9223372036[0-7][0-9]{8}
- 922337203[0-5][0-9]{9}
- 92233720[0-2][0-9]{10}
- 922337[0-1][0-9]{12}
- 92233[0-6][0-9]{13}
- 9223[0-2][0-9]{14}
- 922[0-2][0-9]{15}
- 92[0-1][0-9]{16}
- 9[01][0-9]{17}
- [1-8][0-9]{18}
- [0-9]{0,18}

There's a single digit different in the negative vs. positive, so you'll see where I had to basically duplicate most of this.

So a few question:

1. Did I do this right?
2. If not, what's a better way?
3. Can this be done without regular expressions considering the size of the number? I need to validate client-side.
4. Can it be refactored and still retain strict rules?

Suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this be done without regular expressions considering the size of the number?

It can be done in a series of `if` statements using only string operations (no need to convert to numbers).

- all strings that don't match [0-9]{1,19} are out
- all candidates that are of length 18 or less are good
- for length 19 you can work with string comparison to see if they are numerically less than your upper limit
- tweak the above to take care of negative numbers

Comment: I'm not a pro at performance testing. I did think about breaking it down into a series of "if" statements. Do you think that would perform better? If the performance is minor, I may opt to leave it in one big regex due to lots of other reasons not worth cluttering my question with.

Comment: Performance difference is probably minor (considering whatever the rest of the program does). I would avoid big regex for readibility alone.

Comment: crazy idea break the string into known chuncks and then compare the separate strings with known numeric ranges i.e numbers -20 < x < 20. x=12 first length comparison then x1 = 1 x2=1 li1=2 li2=0 if(li1>x1 || li1===x1 && li2>x2) then the number is bellow the allowed lower limit. just a thought. if the problem is too big to solve it. break it down into smaller pieces

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct.
This is a shorter version

`^(?:-9223372036854775808|-?(?:\d{0,18}|(?!922337203685477580[8-9]|92233720368547758[1-9]|92233720368547759|922337203685477[6-9]|92233720368547[8-9]|9223372036854[8-9]|922337203685[5-9]|92233720368[6-9]|92233720369|922337203[7-9]|92233720[4-9]|9223372[1-9]|922337[3-9]|92233[8-9]|9223[4-9]|922[4-9]|92[3-9]|9[3-9])\d{19}))$`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yB4uB4/2)

How to generate that regex without mistake:
Input max number:

```
9223372036854775807
```

[**Output**:](https://regex101.com/r/eG0cZ2/1)

```
9223372036854775807
922337203685477580
92233720368547758
9223372036854775
922337203685477
92233720368547
9223372036854
922337203685
92233720368
9223372036
922337203
92233720
9223372
922337
92233
9223
922
92
9
```

Replace last number letter

```
9->remove all line
8->9
7->[8-9]
6->[7-9]
5->[6-9]
4->[5-9]
3->[4-9]
2->[3-9]
1->[2-9]
0->[1-9]
```

[**Output**:](https://regex101.com/r/mJ0oW7/2)

```
922337203685477580[8-9]
92233720368547758[1-9]
92233720368547759
922337203685477[6-9]
92233720368547[8-9]
9223372036854[8-9]
922337203685[5-9]
92233720368[6-9]
92233720369
922337203[7-9]
92233720[4-9]
9223372[1-9]
922337[3-9]
92233[8-9]
9223[4-9]
922[4-9]
92[3-9]
9[3-9]
```

[Regex **[Output]**](https://regex101.com/r/lO4iP5/2)
`922337203685477580[8-9]|92233720368547758[1-9]|92233720368547759|922337203685477[6-9]|92233720368547[8-9]|9223372036854[8-9]|922337203685[5-9]|92233720368[6-9]|92233720369|922337203[7-9]|92233720[4-9]|9223372[1-9]|922337[3-9]|92233[8-9]|9223[4-9]|922[4-9]|92[3-9]|9[3-9]`

Add these[output] to regex

> (?!**output**)\d{19}

[Will become [**output2**]](https://regex101.com/r/bD9rQ9/3)

`(?!922337203685477580[8-9]|92233720368547758[1-9]|92233720368547759|922337203685477[6-9]|92233720368547[8-9]|9223372036854[8-9]|922337203685[5-9]|92233720368[6-9]|92233720369|922337203[7-9]|92233720[4-9]|9223372[1-9]|922337[3-9]|92233[8-9]|9223[4-9]|922[4-9]|92[3-9]|9[3-9])\d{19}`

**Matches `\d{19}` <= `9223372036854775807`**

Add

> ^(?:-9223372036854775808|-?(?:\d{0,18}|**[output2]**))$

`^(?:-9223372036854775808|-?(?:\d{0,18}|(?!922337203685477580[8-9]|92233720368547758[1-9]|92233720368547759|922337203685477[6-9]|92233720368547[8-9]|9223372036854[8-9]|922337203685[5-9]|92233720368[6-9]|92233720369|922337203[7-9]|92233720[4-9]|9223372[1-9]|922337[3-9]|92233[8-9]|9223[4-9]|922[4-9]|92[3-9]|9[3-9])\d{19}))$`

Will match

**`-9223372036854775808` or

+/- `\d{0,18}` or

+/- `\d{19}` <= `9223372036854775807`**

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yB4uB4/2)

Comment: This looks really great. I need to review a bit closer, as I'm not immediately understanding all the steps you're taking. Will report back after I get a few hours of sleep :) Thank you very much.